# Is there any Issue using <Buttons> inside of <Row><Col>s?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

This is not the first time I've encountered an issue almost exactly like this, wherein I have a react-bootstrap `<Button>` inside of a react-bootstrap `<Col>` inside of a `' and that button will simply not be clickable.
Earlier, I was able to circumvent this by removing the  from the  it was in, into something less nested, but this time that does not seem to be a viable option. My code looks as follows...

```
<div style={{borderColor: "grey", borderWidth: .5, border: 'solid'}}>
      <Row>
          <Col sm={10}>
              <input type='text' onChange={(event) => handleTextChange(event.target.value)} value={typedMessage} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}/>
          </Col>
       <Col sm={2}>
          <Button style={{width: '100%', marginLeft: 0}} onClick={() => handleSendMessage()}>
             Send
          </Button>
       </Col>
     </Row>
</div>
```

Where right now, `handleSendMessage()` just has a `console.log("Hit send")` inside of it. When I hover over the button, it has the finger pointer, yet when I click there is no shading / opacity animation like there usually is, and no console.log statement. Does anyone have any ideas how to correct this?

Comment: How does your handleSendMessage looks exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your handleSendMessage looks like exactly, but I copy/pasted your code and run it - it works:

https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-fog-3ccjr1